# .NET / Entity Framework Core / SQL Server Procedures Returning Repeated Values

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, api, stored-procedures

I am building my first .NET, Entity Framework, & Angular project and I'm running into a snag with my API. I have created three procedures in SQL Server that run exactly the way I need them to. I then created a small API that runs these three procedures and returns the results.

The strange part is, the result of the API is the first row repeated for the amount of records that the procedure returns. In other words, if the procedure returns 20 unique records, the API returns the first record 20 times.

Here is my API controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using MyApp.Models;
using MyApp.Persistence;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
//using System.Data;
using AutoMapper;

namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext context;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        public CustomerController(MyDbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        // ex: /api/Customer/GetCustomerDetails/0000000632/
        [HttpGet("/api/Customer/GetCustomerDetails/{customerNumber}")] 
        public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerDetail>> GetCustomerDetails(string customerNumber)
        {
            var custNum = new SqlParameter("@custNum", customerNumber);
            return await context.CustomerDetails.FromSql("sp_MyApp_GetCustomerDetails @custNum", custNum).ToArrayAsync();
        }

        // ex: /api/Customer/GetCustomerTransactions/0000000632/2013-01-01T00:00:00.0000000/2017-09-26T23:59:59.0000000/
        [HttpGet("/api/Customer/GetCustomerTransactions/{customerNumber}/{startDate}/{endDate}")] 
        public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerTransaction>> GetCustomerTransactions(string customerNumber, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
        {
            var custNum = new SqlParameter("@custNum", customerNumber);
            var dateFrom = new SqlParameter("@dateFrom", startDate);
            var dateTo = new SqlParameter("@dateTo", endDate);
            return await context.CustomerTransactions.FromSql("sp_MyApp_GetCustomerTransactions @custNum, @dateFrom, @dateTo", custNum, dateFrom, dateTo).ToArrayAsync();
        }

        // ex: /api/Customer/GetCustomerTransactionDetails/0000000632/340084/12531/
        [HttpGet("/api/Customer/GetCustomerTransactionDetails/{customerNumber}/{storeNumber}/{transactionNumber}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<CustomerTransactionDetail>> GetCustomerTransactionDetails(string customerNumber, string storeNumber, string transactionNumber)
        {
            var custNum = new SqlParameter("@custNum", customerNumber);
            var storeNum = new SqlParameter("@storeNum", storeNumber);
            var transNum = new SqlParameter("@transNum", transactionNumber);
            return await context.TransactionDetails.FromSql("sp_MyApp_GetCustomerTransactionDetails @custNum, @storeNum, @transNum", custNum, storeNum, transNum).ToArrayAsync();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Slight detour...http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Does `context.CustomerDetails.FromSql("sp_BrightApp_GetCustomerDetails @custNum", custNum).Count()` return a correct value?

Comment: I just tested the count on each API request, and it does return the correct number of values (count is correct). The problem occurs when I return an array - the first value is duplicated for the number of records returned.

Comment: Can you test with `AsNoTracking()` option (just to see if there is query materialization issue)

Comment: @IvanStoev - That worked perfectly... Did I do something wrong in my EF setup? If you 'answer my question', I will gladly accept it. More information wouldn't hurt either!

Comment: In EF6, this is nearly always caused by EF using a primary key property that's not unique. EF-core, I'm not sure if it has the same behavior in this.

Comment: I can't provide concrete answer without having the entity model and the result set of the stored procedure. It was basically shooting in the dark. But I was suspecting some incorrect primary key setup or sp returning duplicate PKs. See @GertArnold comment.

Comment: Well thank you both very much! I'm working with a pretty wacky database with super loose keys so that's probably why.

Answer (score 3):

This Problem is Easy to Fall into.  You will get no explicit error.  At Runtime you will notice multiple results for the same record.  When you test the stored proc or query outside of EF it will run correctly.

**It is the [Key] Decoration on the Class or Model you are using.**

There is a high likelihood that you are re-using an object that is correct at the field level but the key is not a single primary key field.  Your symptom will be the correct number of records but it is the same data repeated over and over for each record by the EntityFrameworkCore .

If you need a composite multiple field key you will need to use the Fluent API. 
There is a simple example for multiple field composite keys here …

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys

The comments above in the original question are very helpful.